# Firebase Functions: Authentication. onDelete() triggers when a new user is created

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

###### Update 04-10-2023:

I updated firebase-tools on my system, and now my triggers work as they should. If anyone runs into the same issue in the future, consider doing the same. To update, I ran `npm install -g firebase-tools`

##### I'm scratching my head about this problem:

I created a simple auth trigger function, that generates a document in my Cloud Firestore, whenever a new user account is created. This has been working fine for a while.

Now I've been wanting to add a new function, that deletes this document again, when the respective account is deleted.

**However** to my surprise, the .onDelete() trigger also fires, when a new user is being created. In turn, my user document is being created and instantly deleted again...

I'm working this out on the firebase emulator, because I have a production app running and don't want to mess with the active user base of course.

This is my code, it's as simple as it gets. What am I doing wrong?! Is this a severe bug on Firebase's side, or am I missing something here?

```
exports.initializeUserDocUponRegistration = functions.region("europe-west1").auth.user().onCreate(
  async (user) => {
    await db
      .doc(`users/${user.uid}`)
      .set(
        {
          uid: user.uid,
        },
      );
  });

exports.deleteUserDocsUponAccountDeletion = functions.region("europe-west1").auth.user().onDelete(
  async (user) => {
    const userDocRef = db.collection("users").doc(user.uid);
    await db.recursiveDelete(userDocRef);
  });
```

And these are the function logs, when I create a new user.
[image: These are the function logs, when I create a new user]

Comment: If this is easy, straightforward, and reliable to reproduce with minimal code in a fresh project, you should [file an issue with firebase-tools on GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools). You should also consider trying this in a real project.  It doesn't have to be one you use in production.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I didn't want to go that way, but for a lack of better options, I created a new firebase project and can confirm, that the triggers work fine in a real project. Might be an issue of the firebase emulator, a puzzling one nonetheless.

Comment: Sounds like you found a bug in the emulator suite.  I found one today as well.  You should definitely file it.

Comment: I have just tested this with the emulator suite and the onDelete() auth trigger only runs when a user is deleted.

Comment: Your logs don't currently show which user ID is being added or purged. Do they actually correspond to the same user ID? It's probably a good idea to log the subject of that run of the Cloud Function even if you could dive into the execution logs to find it. My current untested theory is that an anonymous user might be converting to a full user and the data associated with the anonymous user ID is being purged.

Comment: @samthecodingman thanks for the suggestion, I added the user ID to the logs now, that makes total sense

UPDATE: I updated firebase-tools on my system, and now my triggers work as they should. I still wonder why this bug ever happened, though, since my previous firebase-tools version was maybe 2 months old, but I'm happy now.